# Set Facebook profile picture without clipping from top in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have Facebook profile images which are usually big in width/height. I am trying to show them in `UITableView`'s header.

Right Now I am using `ContentModeAspectFill`. However the images are getting cut from top. I want the image bounds to start from y=0. Why are the images clipping from the top?

Any ideas how can I make `UIImageView` not clipping the image from the top? I have already tried this:

```
  NSArray *mainArrayOfPaths = [self.thisUser.imagePath componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
for (int x = 0; x < mainArrayOfPaths.count; x++)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [mainArrayOfPaths objectAtIndex:x]);
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = profileHeader.userDpScroll.frame.size.width * x;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = profileHeader.userDpScroll.frame.size;

    UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [imgView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[mainArrayOfPaths objectAtIndex:x]] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
     {
     }];
    [imgView sizeToFit];
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    imgView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    imgView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    imgView.frame = frame;
    imgView.tag = x;
    imgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    [imgView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [imgView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openFullScreenImg:)];

    [imgView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    //[imgView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    //[imgView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
    [profileHeader.userDpScroll addSubview:imgView];
}
```

Comment: Did you check the other content modes?

Comment: It would be nice of you to accept a correct answer to your question by clicking the gray checkmark next to it.

Comment: @Rajesh If the answers are not satisfying what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

Normally for such things I use `NINetworkImageView` from [Nimbus](https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus/tree/master/src/networkimage/src) you have there a few possibilities by setting content mode and **displaySize** and **cropRect** which I believe will do the job you want! I have done many cropping issues with that component so it should be applied for your case as well.

Try to play with this method from `NINetworkImageView`:

```
- (void)setPathToNetworkImage:(NSString *)pathToNetworkImage forDisplaySize:(CGSize)displaySize contentMode:(UIViewContentMode)contentMode cropRect:(CGRect)cropRect
```

**Moreover this library will handle lazy loading and caching for you.**

At least you can take a look how they handle these kind of cases :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the imgView.contentMode to either of the following three options

UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,

UIViewContentModeTopLeft,

UIViewContentModeTop

based upon your requirement.

UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill by definition itself clips part of the content if necessary to fill the image rect maintaining the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

these two lines should work

```
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;//it will not crop the image but will try to adjust image in image view frame
imgView.clipsToBounds = YES; // it will help you cliping the content of image to image view bound
```

but in case its not working you should check FBProfilePictureView (found in facebook sdk), for details check this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBProfilePictureView/)